# How to view alternate mime content in Wanderlust

Tags: linux, emacs, imap, mime

How can I view alternate mime content in Wanderlust?

All my mails are coming through as the HTML version, and sometimes I'd rather see the plain text version, even though I don't want to lose the ability to see HTML version altogether.

Comment: No, Wanderlust is a mailclient for emacs

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/435668/how-to-view-alternate-mime-content-in-wanderlust

Answer (score 1):

I have (in ~/.wl)

```
(setq mime-view-type-subtype-score-alist
  '(((text . plain) . 4)
    ((text . enriched) . 3)
    ((text . html) . 2)
    ((text . richtext) . 1)))
```

to set the default priorities (I like plain text better, but just change the values if you want html most of the time).

Then, when I want to see the alternate version, I display all the message parts with (in summary buffer)

```
C-c m runs the command wl-summary-toggle-mime-buttons
```

Which displays as `[1  <text/plain; UTF-8 (7bit)>]` and `[2  <text/html; UTF-8 (quoted-printable)>]`

Jumping to the message buffer, and putting cursor on the appropriate button,

```
C-c C-t C-c runs the command mime-preview-toggle-content
```

which toggles display of that particular part.